# Codeigniter caching - suggestions to refresh after new post

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, memcached, outputcache

I have a blog-type app built on CI 2.1.0.
When I add

```
$this->output->cache(5);
```

to my controller, CI correctly caches the page, and it loads quickly.

My issue is that if someone comments on that post, the comment will not show until the cache expires.

I wonder if anyone has pointers on how to force a cache refresh everytime there is a change to that specific page, or if a post edit is made, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the CodeIgniter documentation:

> If you no longer wish to cache a file you can remove the caching tag
>   and it will no longer be refreshed when it expires. Note: Removing the
>   tag will not delete the cache immediately. It will have to expire
>   normally. If you need to remove it earlier you will need to manually
>   delete it from your cache folder.

For programatically delete the cache file you can use

[CodeIgniter Cache Helper](https://bitbucket.org/stevenbenner/codeigniter-cache-helper)

Here this function will delete the cache file

```
function delete_cache($uri_string)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
        $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;

        $uri =  $CI->config->item('base_url').
            $CI->config->item('index_page').
            $uri_string;

        $cache_path .= md5($uri);

        if (file_exists($cache_path))
        {
            return unlink($cache_path);
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: of course i do not want to manually delete, as i'm not sure even which of the cached files points to the page that was updated - how would one selectively delete that file on update programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the output class to enable clear page cache. Take a look here :  https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Clear-Page-Cache